# AspectJ: pointcut after completed object initialization

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I want to add an advice that runs for each object created from a set of classes (in my case, from a specific package) after initialization is complete. Consider this code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A();
        new A(0);
        new B();
        new B(0);
        new B(false);
    }
}

class A {
    public A() {
    }

    public A(int i) {
        this();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B() {
    }

    public B(int i) {
        this();
    }

    public B(boolean b) {
        super(0);
    }
}
```

for example, for `new B(false)`, the advise should run after `public B(boolean)`, but not after `public A(int)` of after `public A()`. Also note that I don't want to advise the constructor calls in `main()`; if objects are constructed from a 3rd party application that's not compiled with my aspect, the advise should still be there, i.e. the constructors themselves should be advised.

I thought this should work using some !cflowbelow() expression, but I had no luck. The closest I got is this:

```
after() : initialization(pkg.*.new(..))
        && !cflowbelow(withincode(pkg.*.new(..)))
        && !within(MyAspect) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart);
}
```

which gives this output:

```
initialization(test.A())

initialization(test.A(int))

initialization(test.A())
initialization(test.B())

initialization(test.A())
initialization(test.B(int))

initialization(test.A(int))
initialization(test.B(boolean))
```

i.e. `this()` executions are ignored correctly, but `super()` executions are not. Also, I fear this will ignore things like `public B() {new A();}` or similar, because `new A();` is in a `pkg.*.new(..)` cflowbelow...

I can't imagine this isn't a use case that's useful over and over, but I didn't find any resources on it. An example where full initialization is necessary would be when logging newly created objects, but the toString() method uses the object's state. Advising anything else but the "subclass-most" constructor will yield in a log containing uninitialized values, and advising constructor calls will, as I said, not work with third party code (or code from a different package in my example).

For extra internet-cookies, how would I select the bottom-most (non-Object or other non-unadvised-superclass) constructor for injectting pre-initialization code?